# How to add a session in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

we're working on a project for our Programming-Course. We're doing a very small social media platform, where you can register, login, create a profile, view events and log out.

So I set the session variable for logging in, but I also want that people who register are instantly logged in and get redirected to the profile-site. So I have to set another session into the registration app.post I guess, but I have absolutly no Idea how to do this (because I'm a bloody beginner)... Can anybody help? This is the code so far:

```
//------------Sessionvariables---------------//
app.get('/', requiresLogin, function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        'username': req.session.user.name
    });
});

app.post('/sendLogin', function(req, res) {
    //in Datenbank gucken
    const user = req.body["username"];
    const password = req.body["password"];
    db.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='${user}'`, function(err, row) {
        if (row != undefined) {
            if(password == row.password) {
                req.session['user'] = user;
                res.redirect('/home');
            }else{
                res.redirect('/loginerror');
            }
        }else{
            res.redirect('/loginerror');
        }
        if(err){
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    });
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
      if (err) return next(err)
        req.session = null;
      res.redirect('/start-login');
    });
});

// Registration
app.post('/registration', function(req, res) {
    const { email, password, username, domicile } = req.body;
        // validation
    db.run(`INSERT INTO users(email,password,username,domicile) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`, [email, password, username, domicile], function(err) {
         if (err) {
             return console.log(err.message);
         }
         return res.redirect('/edit_profile');
     });
});
```

I know that I have to write the session into the app.post /registration - Part, but I don't know how to write it. I'm using Node js, Express and sqlite3...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
// Registration
app.post('/registration', function(req, res) {
    const { email, password, username, domicile } = req.body;
        // validation
    db.run(`INSERT INTO users(email,password,username,domicile) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`, [email, password, username, domicile], function(err) {
         if (err) {
             return console.log(err.message);
         } else {
             // Create the session / save any data you want here
             req.session.user.name = username;
             /* I would actually call somthing like: createSession(req)
                dedicated function that nicely creates the session */
             // Redirect to home just like you do after successful login
             res.redirect('/home'); // Redirect to home since user registered successfully
         }
     });
});
```

By the way always treat error before running other code logic i see you are treating errors at the end of code (in the `app.post('/sendLogin',...)` :

```
if(err){
  console.error(err.message);
}
```

Write like this:

```
if(err){
  console.error(err.message);
  // and res.end() or similar if its in an express route
} else {
  // Do safe stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best method i can suggest you is that after registration success set the user details in session and just redirect to your home page